# how to fire click event on document ready...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, click, document-ready

Radio Button

```
<input name="radio-choice-t-6" class="qololbl" id="radio-choice-t-6a" value="qolo" checked="checked" type="radio">
<label for="radio-choice-t-6a" style="border: 1px solid #2d5f7c;width:90px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px;border-top-left-radius:4px;font-family:Noto Sans;">Toast</label>

$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $('.qololbl').trigger('click'); 

    $(".qololbl").click(function(){
        alert("Hi");
     });
});
```

how to fire qololbl click event on document ready. this code is not working why..?
thanks in advance.
help me

Comment: You are firing the `click` event before you've set up a `click` event handler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `.click()` instead of `.trigger()`. And put it after event hanlder declaration.

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $(".qololbl").click(function(){
        alert("Hi");
     });
     
     $('.qololbl').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="radio-choice-t-6" class="qololbl" id="radio-choice-t-6a" value="qolo" checked="checked" type="radio">
<label for="radio-choice-t-6a" style="border: 1px solid #2d5f7c;width:90px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px;border-top-left-radius:4px;font-family:Noto Sans;">Toast</label>
```

Alternative (Suggested by [pratik-gaikwad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2398353/pratik-gaikwad))

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $(".qololbl").on('click', function(){
        alert("Hi");
     });
     
     $('.qololbl').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="radio-choice-t-6" class="qololbl" id="radio-choice-t-6a" value="qolo" checked="checked" type="radio">
<label for="radio-choice-t-6a" style="border: 1px solid #2d5f7c;width:90px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px;border-top-left-radius:4px;font-family:Noto Sans;">Toast</label>
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `on` instead of click to register and then use `trigger` .

Answer (score 2):

The code executes line by line. You are triggering the click event before applying the event to the element. This is why no event is being fired and no alert is being launched.

See Leguest [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43919604/3176945) for correct ordering.